# Pandas - Retrieve Value from df.loc

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Using pandas I have a result (here aresult) from a df.loc lookup that python is telling me is a 'Timeseries'.

sample of predictions.csv:

```
prediction     id
1              593960337793155072
0              991960332793155071
....
```

code to retrieve one prediction

```
predictionsfile = pandas.read_csv('predictions.csv')
idtest = 593960337793155072

result = (predictionsfile.loc[predictionsfile['id'] == idtest])
aresult = result['prediction']
```

A result retreives a data format that cannot be keyed:

```
In: print aresult
    11    1
    Name: prediction, dtype: int64
```

I just need the prediction, which in this case is 1. I've tried aresult['result'], aresult[0] and aresult[1] all to no avail. Before I do something awful like converting it to a string and strip it out, I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: Please add reproducible code to your question, at least a sample of the original dataframe you're working on.

Comment: I think you want `aresult['result'].values[0]`

Comment: @EdChum No unfortunately it won't let me key it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series requires .item() to retrieve its value.

```
print aresult.item()
1
```